# Java DES encryption with CBC gives different results each time it is run

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, des

I'm trying to use JDK 1.7 JCE (Windows 7 x64) to perform Single DES encryption with CBC on a small block.  Each time I run the program below I get different results.  The key is the same, the data is the same, what could be wrong?

```
public class CBCTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Cipher cc = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
        Key k = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[] {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, "DES");
        cc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] data = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        cc.doFinal(data);
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + Arrays.toString(cc.doFinal(data)));
    }
}
```

Edit:
Changing the  Cipher mode to ECB `"DES/CBC/NoPadding"` works without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CBC mode there is a further input namely the IV (initialization vector). Make sure to use the same IV for each run then you will get identical output.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/IvParameterSpec.html) for the details.

Btw. it is not a bad idea to use a random IV, this makes sure that there is a different ciphertext each time if the same message is sent several times. This is especially important if the number of possible messages is low. It makes it much harder for an eavesdropper to guess the meaning of a certain bit pattern.

Comment: In my case I do want the same IV, so just adding it to the init call does the trick.

Comment: It is in fact a very bad idea to use a static IV. That pretty much defeats the purpose of CBC mode over ECB mode.